# Is the copy constructor always called when returning by value in C++

Tags: c++, return-value, copy-constructor

Does the compiler always call a copy constructor when it returns an object by value in C++?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the so far listed candidates. They do not consider move semantics.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - The consensus on meta is to improve canonical duplicate with up to date information. Not to spuriously reopen questions.

Answer (score 1):

No. The compiler is allowed to elide the call to the copy constructor in some cases. Look up RVO (Return Value Optimization) and NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization). Also, since C++17, this optimization is *guaranteed* in some cases.

Additionally, if the returned type is movable, the compiler may do a move rather than a copy in some cases.